# Android: how to see array content using debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I want to see content of array using debugger lets say I have an array and in the for loop I'm adding more items to array how can I see what are the current values in array and after update

```
     imageArray[i] = url+logo;
     nameArray[i] = name;
```

also what does it mean when infront of variable or array its: 'this' is not available[image: image is here]

Comment: Just add a breakpoint on the line and start your app using the debug button.

Comment: It didn't work thats why asked

Comment: Is it inside any listeners ????

Comment: Are you sure you clicked on the right button like shown on this image? http://i.imgur.com/cFDEFBS.png

Comment: lol yes @Denny sure, the output is this: arrayname 'this' is not available

Comment: its inside for loop and for loop is inside try block @MaharithAdityaSS

Comment: Can you Please Post the Code

Comment: Does debugging code before your try or loop work? And as I understand you use `this` as variable name, maybe that causes the problem since it's a keyword for Java.

Comment: added image in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Here is step by step :

step 1:Add debugger below the array as shown

[image: Add debugger below the array as shown]

step 2: Select the array and right click on it and select Evaluate Expression as shown

[image: Select the array and right click on it and select Evaluate Expression as shown]

Step 3: Then press enter you will see the content of the array

[image: Then press enter you will see the content of the array]

Comment: could you tell me what does it mean, arrayname  = 'this' is not available

Comment: arrayname is the name of your array for example imageArray that you have posted in your question.

Comment: I will post image

Comment: added image in question

Comment: this is the additional information of the object if you want to look at it but I think you only need to look at the top most info that is JasonObject.

Comment: Are you Pakistani